# zip files in a directory based on a pattern before moving to archive location

Tags: zip

For example in data directory I have files like `CODE_A1_timestamp.txt`, `CODE_A2_timestamp.txt` and `DOCI_A1_Timestamp.txt`. I only need to zip files with pattern `CODE_A1*` i.e. `CODE_A1_timestamp.txt` file before moving it to archive directory.

Answer (score 2):

**zip only**

Include only the specified files, as in:

```
zip foo . -i CODE_A1\*
```

**find and zip**

You can use find with not-recursive-option (`-maxdepth 1`) like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'CODE_A1*' | zip foo -@
```